# Date Picker in Android

Tags: android

I want to display a date picker for selecting  date of birth,so as to user restricted to choose future date.currently date picker displays all dates including future also.i want to show the dates up to current dates only.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Date Picker Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html)?  Then just extend it to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It's some what hard to explain how to create a Date Picker. What's better is looking at the sample code from the Android API Demos which shows you how to do a Date Picket and much more. You can figure out how to download these API Demos at: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setMaxDate` function, and set that to the current date

```
    Datepicker dp = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
    // Set it to only show past dates...
    dp.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#getMaxDate%28%29))